# Не могу вернуть кортеж из метода С#

Tags: c#

[image: Та самая ошибка]

Не могу вернуть поле стринг(slots[index].number) и инт(collision), в ошибке пишется
"Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "System.Tuple<string,int>" в "(string,int)". (см. картинку)
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем дело

Comment: А что именно и какого типа у вас программа ожидает получить из этого return?

Comment: Добрый день, ожидает стрингу и инт

Comment: А почему тогда возврат называется MyTuple? :-) Не знаком с C#, но разве это не один кортеж из двух элементов, вместо отдельных двух элементов?

Comment: `(...)` и `Tuple` это немного разные вещи, тут стоит выбрать какой именно вид вы хотите, тот и использовать везде. Например заменить `Tuple.Create(...)` на `(slots[intex].number, collision)`, либо как вы написали в ответе, наоборот, заменить `(string, int)` на `Tuple<string,int>`.

Comment: Код надо вставлять текстом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выяснил, что перед именем метода нужно (string,int) заменить на Tuple<string,int>

Comment: Создай лучше класс и возвращай его, а не кортеж. Пройдёт месяц и ты/другой программист не будете знать, что возращает метод. Не могу придумать ни одной ситуации, когда возращать кортеж лучше, чем класс

Comment: И поработай над названиями методов. Find - не говорит ни о чём. Переименуй это название на говорящее - то, что действительно делает этот метод. Пример FindNameById(Guid userId)